# How do I disable the graphs on the startup screen of Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

When I start up Wireshark, it begins monitoring all the interfaces on my PC and shows me graphs of how much traffic is on each interface.

[image: picture of the Wireshark start-up screen with the graphs circled]

On Windows this generates ~15 consecutive UAC prompts. I can get around this by allowing non-admin users to capture network traffic (which seems bad from a security perspective) or by launching Wireshark as administrator (Wireshark warns you not to do this on other platforms. It seems like good advice on Windows as well).

Is there any way to configure Wireshark to *not* open every network adapter on the system just to show me these graphs?

Comment: How about the option `Don't load interfaces at startup`?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Once I turn that on, is there a way to start a capture for a single interface?

Comment: Well, sort of. It asks you to refresh your interfaces to load them, which will most probably only postpone your problem to that step.

Comment: Btw, my installation does not show the behavior you described. And I'm pretty sure that it's the default configuration, I hardly use it and usually don't change anything in the configuration.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider It does indeed re-prompt (many times) when I refresh interfaces. The default is for the [Restrict Npcap driver's access to Administrators only](https://www.softperfect.com/media/b9fab781-ac9e-469b-9698-cd1514aa7f07.png) option to be un-checked, which I imagine is why you are not running into this issue. I might give in and change that setting, but I was just looking for other options.